# How to run cron once, daily at 10pm

Tags: bash, cron, system, scheduled-tasks

I had entered:

```
* 22 * * * test > /dev/null
```

However, I am being notified via email that this is running every minute.
I am confused I guess because I thought this was correct for what I am wanting.

Comment: This website will explain any cron schedule: https://crontab.guru/

Answer (score 446, accepted):

It's running every minute of the hour 22 I guess. Try the following to run it every first minute of the hour 22:

```
0 22 * * * ....
```

Comment: Although the hour 22 might be relatively save, please consider the first case of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52354269/562769)

Comment: @MartinThoma always try `man cron` first, you should find what you are looking for.

Comment: Remember to check the system's date, it happened to me to set crontab to start a job at 22, but it actually started at 23 because the system was UTC (so 22 for the system was 23 for me in GMT).

Comment: I upvoted this answer but I did know this rule... anyway I wanted to confirm my silent knowledge :D

Answer (score 193):

Here are some more examples

- Run every 6 hours at 46 mins past the hour:

  `46     */6     *     *     *`
- Run at 2:10 am:

  `10     2     *     *     *`
- Run at 3:15 am:

  `15     3     *     *     *`
- Run at 4:20 am:

  `20     4     *     *     *`
- Run at 5:31 am:

  `31     5     *     *     *`
- Run at 5:31 pm:

  `31     17    *    *    *`

Comment: Good examples to understand the cron syntax

Answer (score 70):

To run once, daily at 10PM you should do something like this:

```
0 22 * * *
```

[image]

Full size image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeXHD.jpg

**Source:** [softpanorama.org](http://www.softpanorama.org/Utilities/cron.shtml)

Comment: Apologies for the bad picture size.

Answer (score 34):

Here is what I look at everytime I am writing a new crontab entry:

To start editing from terminal -type:

```
 zee$ crontab -e
```

what you will add to crontab file:

```
0 22 * * 0  some-user /opt/somescript/to/run.sh
```

What it means:

```
[ 
+ user => 'some-user',      
+ minute => ‘0’,             <<= on top of the hour.
+ hour => '22',              <<= at 10 PM. Military time.
+ monthday => '*',           <<= Every day of the month*
+ month => '*',              <<= Every month*
+ weekday => ‘0’,            <<= Everyday (0 thru 6) = sunday thru saturday
]
```

Also, check what shell your machine is running and name the the file accordingly OR it wont execute.

Check the shell with either `echo $SHELL` or `echo $0`

It can be "Bourne shell `(sh)` , Bourne again shell `(bash)`,Korn shell `(ksh)`..etc"

Comment: Your command shows 0 for the weekday, but your explanation shows it as *

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for crontab

```
* * * * * 

Minute(0-59) Hour(0-24) Day_of_month(1-31) Month(1-12) Day_of_week(0-6) Command_to_execute
```

Your syntax

```
* 22 * * * test > /dev/null
```

your job will Execute every minute at 22:00 hrs all week, month and year.

adding an option (0-59) at the minute place will run it once at 22:00 hrs all week, month and year.

```
0 22 * * * command_to_execute
```

Source https://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference